# How to remove horizontal scroll in JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Is there a way to remove horizontal scroll in a `JScrollPane` that contains a `JTextArea`?

Or make it so that when the text reaches the end, of the line, instead of scrolling horizontally, it prints `"\n"` to start a new line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>For the scroll pane:</s>

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

For the text area (set word wrap):

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

**EDIT:** as mentioned in the comments, the first part (crossed out) is redundant

Comment: (1+) There is no need to set the horizontal scroll policy of the JScrollPane. The point of using the setLineWrap(....) on the JTextArea.  is so the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear.

Comment: @eddie read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for a working example. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for tutorials on other Swing basics.

Comment: `scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);`                    is not needed, but thanks works great!